# What is C# equivalent of <map> in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, dictionary, visual-c++, language-comparisons

I have defined a class myComplex. I need to map it to integers. In C++ I would have created a map as 
`map<myComplex,int>` first;

How to do such thing in C#?

Comment: My best guess would be you need a `Dictionary<myComplex, int>` but some more information would be nice.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The equivalent would be class [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

If you don't care about the order the class [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace would probably be sufficient.

Comment: If they don't care about order, `Dictionary` is more than sufficient, it's preferable.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, but that begs the question: why did they use 'map' in C++ if they didn't care about order? They could have used unordered_map in C++ (assuming they've been awake since C++11).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Agreed. My point is just that your statement was that given they don't care about order, `Dictionary` is "probably [...] sufficient". Actually, in the case where they don't care about order, `Dictionary` is more than sufficient; it's preferable.

Answer (score 61):

`std::map<Key, Value>` → [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

`std::unordered_map<Key, Value>` → [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at the [Dictionary class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in System::Collections::Generic.

```
Dictionary<myComplex, int> myMap = new Dictionary<myComplex, int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET Framework provides many collection classes too. You can use Dictionary in C#.
Please find the below msdn link for details and samples
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx