# max amount of same item in a list with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, max

Let's say I have this list:

1
1
1
1
2
2
2
3

I want to narrow it down with C# to a list with a maximum of two same items in a list so it would look like this:

1
1
2
2
3

I used to use 'distinct' like this:

```
string[] array = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\list.txt");
List<string> list = new List<string>(array);
List<string> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

but don't have an idea on how it could bring a max number of same values

Comment: Great idea. What did you try so far?

Comment: I agree with everything above except the great idea bit

Comment: well I tried this:

string[] array = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\list.txt");
            List<string> list = new List<string>(array);
            List<string> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();

but obviously it only brings up distinct items

Comment: @LukasMorkunas You should edit the question to include that code instead of putting it into a comment.

Comment: No no no, put your substantive info in your *question*, not in the comments!

Comment: So why didn't you include this in the question. Your question is not clear pleas read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Even including that code it's not clear what you actually want

Comment: Is it already in order?

Comment: Is each number on a separate line or are they separated by spaces?

Comment: Look into LINQ extension methods `GroupBy`, `Count`, `OrderByDescending`, and `First`. This should give you the toolbox required to solve the problem.

Comment: This should be helpful [**What is C# equivalent of <map> in C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183414/what-is-c-sharp-equivalent-of-map-in-c) where each unique item is the key and its count is the value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do it with Linq as follows.

```
var Groups = Input.GroupBy( i => i );
var Result = Groups.SelectMany( iGroup => iGroup.Take(2) ).ToArray();
```

Comment: I love your name, by the way.

Comment: Well thanks, I took me several attempts to make it up!

Comment: I would upvote an answer that just said codor several times